# table extraction: adding column with file name and path of origin file to df

Tags: python, pandas, docx

i need to extract the same table out of multiple docx report documents.
In the list `'targets_in_dir'` I have stored all the file names with paths in the format

```
'C:\directory\subdirectory\filename1.docx'
```

The code below perfectly grabs the table out of the document and correctly allocates the keys to the columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import docx
from docx.api import Document

document = Document(targets_in_dir[1])
table = document.tables[2]

data = []

keys = None
for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['report'] = targets_in_dir[1]
print (targets_in_dir[1])
```

**My question:** For tracking purpose I want to add a column to the final df where in each line the filename where the row was pulled is added. I tried to do it with the line

```
df['report'] = targets_in_dir[1]
```

but strangely it only adds the data from 'data_1' instead of the filename and path!

| report | data_1 |
| --- | --- |
| C:\directory\subdirectory\filename1.docx | Cumarin |
| C:\directory\subdirectory\filename1.docx | Piperacin |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found a solution myself with the following line of code. i just add `str`

```
df['report'] = str(targets_in_dir[1])
```